# RedirectToAction() method is not returning a 302 status code

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am trying to use a RedirectToAction() method to redirect from one Action to another. However, when I execute my code, I am getting a "200 OK" instead of "302 Found" in the Status Code. [Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hXPi1.png)

Basically, My Save action is supposed to redirect to Index Action but it does not redirect.

Save Action in Movies controller

```
     [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Save(Movies movies)
    {


        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var viewModel = new MovieViewModel
            {
                Generes = _context.Generes.ToList()
            };

            return View("MovieForm", viewModel);
        }

        if (movies.ID == 0)
        {
            movies.DateAdded = DateTime.Now;
            _context.Movies.Add(movies);
        }

        else
        {
            var MoviesInDb = _context.Movies.Single(m => m.ID == movies.ID);

            MoviesInDb.MovieName = movies.MovieName;
            MoviesInDb.Releasedate = movies.Releasedate;
            MoviesInDb.GenereID = movies.GenereID;
            MoviesInDb.NumberInStock = movies.NumberInStock;
        }
        _context.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index","Movies");
    }
```

Index Action In Movies Controller

```
 public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var Movies = _context.Movies.Include(m => m.Genere).ToList();
        return View(Movies);
    }
```

The Index View

```
@model IEnumerable<Vidly.Models.Movies>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<title> Movies</title>
<h2>Movies</h2>

<button class="btn btn-primary"> New Movie </button>
<table class="table table-striped" >
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th> Movies </th>
            <th> Category </th>

        </tr>
    </thead>

    <br/>
    <tbody>

        @foreach (var Movie in Model)
        {

            <tr>

                <td>
                    @Html.ActionLink(Movie.MovieName, "Edit", "Movies", new { id = Movie.ID },null)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Movie.Genere.Name
                </td>

            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And the View that Feeds the Save action is the MovieForm.cshtml

```
  @model Vidly.ViewModels.MovieViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "MovieForm";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Movie Form</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm("Save", "Movies"))
{

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Movies.MovieName)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Movies.MovieName, new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Movies.MovieName)
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Movies.Releasedate)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Movies.Releasedate, "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Movies.Releasedate)
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Movies.GenereID)
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Movies.GenereID, new SelectList(Model.Generes, "ID", "Name"), "Select the Genere", new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Movies.GenereID)
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Movies.NumberInStock)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Movies.NumberInStock, new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Movies.NumberInStock)
    </div>

    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Movies.ID)
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <br />
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"> Submit</button>

}
```

Any idea why it is returning a 200 Ok status Code?

Comment: Are you sure that is the status code sent by the controller upon calling Save or just the status code received after the redirection?

Comment: Hi @RicardoPeres 
The status code is sent by the controller after the Save action has been executed, 
because as soon as I click the submit button the URL changes to localhost50329/Movies/Save from localhost50329/Movies/new. Whereas, the URL was supposed to be directed to  localhost50329/Movies/Index

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps ModelState is not valid

```
...
if (!ModelState.IsValid)
{
  var viewModel = new MovieViewModel
  {
    Generes = _context.Generes.ToList()
  };

  return View("MovieForm", viewModel);
}
...
```